# How to Disable Buttons in a Column Widget While a button is Pressed in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I'm working on a Flutter project where I have a column widget containing a list of ElevatedButtons generated dynamically based on an API response. When a button is pressed, display an AlertDialog. During the time the button was pressed to the AlertDialog is open, I'd like to disable all the buttons in the column to prevent users from interacting with them until the dialog is closed. How can I achieve this functionality?

```
FutureBuilder<Map<String, dynamic>>(
                    future: _apiService.fetchData(),
                    builder: (context, snapshot) {
                      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                        return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                      }
                      if (snapshot.hasError || !snapshot.hasData) {
                        return Center(child: Text('Error: ${snapshot.error ?? "No data"}'));
                      }
                      final String companyName = snapshot.data!['company']?.name ?? '';
                      final List<dynamic> categoriesData = snapshot.data!['categories'] ?? [];

                      return Column(
                        children: categoriesData.map<Widget>((category) {
                          final String nameEn = category.nameEn;
                          final String nameBn = category.nameBn;
                          bool isProcessing = false;
                          bool isButtonEnabled = true;

                          return StatefulBuilder(
                            builder: (context, setState) {
                              final bool isSelected = isLoadingIndex == categoriesData.indexOf(category);

                              return Column(
                                children: [
                                  ElevatedButton(
                                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                                      backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
                                      fixedSize: Size(screenWidth * 0.8, screenHeight * 0.1),
                                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    onPressed: isButtonEnabled ? () async {
                                      setState(() {
                                        isLoadingIndex = categoriesData.indexOf(category);
                                        isButtonEnabled = false;
                                        isProcessing = true;
                                        isButtonPressed = true;
                                      });
                                      final int categoryID = category.id;
                                      final url = URL;
                                      final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));

                                      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
                                        final responseData = json.decode(response.body);
                                        print(responseData);
                                        final data = responseData['data'];
                                        final Token = data['token'];
                                        final Time = data['time'];
                                        print('Token: $Token, Time and Date: $Time');

                                        final SunmiPosSdk sunmiPosSdk = SunmiPosSdk();
                                        await sunmiPosSdk.printReceipt(context, '$Token', '$Time', '$nameEn', '$nameBn', '$companyName');

                                        showDialog(
                                          context: context,
                                          builder: (BuildContext context) {
                                            barrierColor: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5);
                                            barrierDismissible: false;
                                            return Center(
                                              child: buildAlertDialog(Token, Time, '$nameEn ($nameBn)'),
                                            );
                                          },
                                        );
                                      } else {
                                        print('Failed to fetch data: ${response.statusCode}');
                                      }
                                      setState(() {
                                          isLoadingIndex = -1;
                                          isButtonEnabled = true;
                                          isProcessing = false;
                                          isButtonPressed = false;
                                        });
                                    }: null,
                                    child: FittedBox(
                                      fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
                                      child: Text(
                                        '$nameEn ($nameBn)',
                                        style: const TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 25,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                          color: Colors.white,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  if (isProcessing)
                                    GestureDetector(
                                      onTap: () {},
                                      child: Container(
                                        color: Colors.transparent,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  SizedBox(height: screenHeight * 0.01),
                                ],
                              );
                            },
                          );
                        }).toList(),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
```

Comment: Because I was trying to prevent the user from closing the dialog without clicking the 'OK' button.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a check `isDailogBoxOpen` when opening the dialog box set the value of the check to true, and in buttons use this check to make them disable.

Comment: I tried, nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the barrierDismissible inside builder: that's why it is dismissing.

Pass it inside showDialog like this.

```
showDialog( 
 barrierDismissible: false,
)
```

```
         showDialog(
            //this line
              barrierDismissible: false,
              context: context,
              builder: (BuildContext context) {
                barrierColor: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5);
                barrierDismissible: false;
                return Center(
                  child: buildAlertDialog(Token, Time, '$nameEn ($nameBn)'),
                );
              },
            )
```

Now your Dialog will not close without the Button press(Manual Closing).

```
 GestureDetector(
  onTap: () {
   Navigator.of(context).pop();
  },
  child: Text("Ok"),
 ),
```